# Why do we add an Offset when addressing DDRx ,PORTx in avr?

Tags: arduino, avr, avr-gcc, atmel

I recently started programming my **Arduino (ATmega328p)** using AVR and gained sufficient knowledge on using avr lib,instead of arduino IDE.I started with a blink led example.

Then i tried the same eg but this time however i didnot **include io.h** or any other lib,  and instead used pointer to PORTs Like *DDRB or PORTB* etc.

According to atmega328p datasheet, DDRB is at 0x04 and PORTB at 0x05.

However setting them high for my blinking led eg didnot work.
**Instead i had to add an offset of 0x20 to both addresses, after it worked perfectly.**
i.e.,DDRB=0x24 and PORTB=0x25
Where is this offset(0x20) comming from ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the memory map on p.19 of the [datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/images/Atmel-8271-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega48A-48PA-88A-88PA-168A-168PA-328-328P_datasheet_Complete.pdf), you see that the first 32 byte addresses are the registers, and the I/O registers start after these. That is why you need to add a 32 (0x20) offset to get the SRAM address.

Comment: @darth if you use the `sbi` and `cbi` instructions, though, you don't use the offset — e.g. `sbi 0x05, 3` sets PORTB3 to high, and not 0x25.